# Regex Pattern to Parse the formula bar

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I am implementing the formula bar in which there can be any operation with two values like:

```
SUB ( DIV ( ADD (2,5), 4.5 ), AVG (3,4) )
```

So here I need to first call `ADD` operation as its most inner operation, then `DIV` it by some fraction, then calculate the `AVG` and in last `SUB` both the values, so there can be any formula user can put on formula bar.

I am trying to write recursive function for that but before that I need to parse it properly. I could not figure out how to write regex for this kind of pattern..

Any ideas please?

Comment: I would bet that if you posted your recursive function you'd get a better suggestion that didnt require regex.

Comment: Post sample input and expected output please, so people will better understand what regex you want.

Comment: Thanks paqogomez and Tafari for your concern.. actually I have not yet develop any function.. I have only the problem and its up to me to find out the best way.. I thought recursive will be the solution as once I get inner operation result then I will call it again to resolve outer operation..& so on.. here ADD is stands for addition operation, DIV is for division, AVG is for average, SUB is for subtraction..

Comment: output will be like this: ====>
SUB ( DIV ( ADD (2,5), 4.5 ), AVG (3,4) ) ====>

SUB ( DIV (8 , 4.5 ), AVG (3,4) ) =====>

SUB ( 1.77 , AVG (3,4) ) =====>

SUB ( 1.77 , 3.5 ) =====>

-1.73

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If what you are trying to do is break the expression into subexpressions and get the contents of a subexpression between parenthesis - you cannot do this with regular expressions. Regular expressions cannot handle the parenthesis matching problem.

You'd need to devise another algorithm to do that - a stack based approach (push on opening parenthesis, pop on closing parenthesis) could be one approach.

Here's a related question about this issue: [Regular Expression to match outer brackets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/546433/regular-expression-to-match-outer-brackets)

However, you could use a regex to validate/parse leaf expressions (the ones with no nested expressions) in the expression tree, once you've got your expression broken down.

EDIT: while the above is true for regular expressions in general as a language (as taught in CS classes), libraries have made enhancements to the language to allow this. Perl has done this for a long time, and it seems it's possible in .NET as well. Here's a post explaining Balanced Matching in the .NET Regex implementation.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bclteam/archive/2005/03/15/396452.aspx